# Using shift + print screen only does a full pag screenshot not sure how to fix it

Tags: gnome-screenshot

So I'm trying to use shift + print screen to take a partial screenshot of a page but it only does a full page shot. I didn't have this issue before and i am not sure how to remedy the situation. i used the command gnome-screenshot -a but the problem i have with that is I cant move the terminal page out the way to take the shot.

Comment: Does ctrl+shift work? I'm on debian now, but both key combinations do the same work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First try restarting your computer.
If it doesn't fix itself, then you can see the keyboard shortcuts in  Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and edit those.

Shortcut for taking screenshot of an area is listed under `Screenshots`

[image]

You can change it to your choice by clicking on it and then pressing your new "key action" and then clicking set.

Hope his fixes your issue.

Comment: thank you i just switched the shortcut to just print and it fixed the issue

Comment: I had the same question, thanks for the answer. It appears that Ubuntu 22.04 swapped the default shortcuts, so printscreen is bound to the interactive screenshot, whereas shift+printscreen does the entire screen. Perhaps the reasoning is the user might want the interactive screenshot more often.